# what's the meaning of global variable _ which convers nil to an interface

Tags: go, variables, interface

I am trying to understand the effect of global variable _ from graph's source code like the belowing code, but at last I can't figure out what's the meaning.

```
type variable_ interface {
    cin()
}

type imple struct {
}

func (i *imple) cin() {
    fmt.Println("cout")
}

var (
    _ = variable_((*imple)(nil))
)
```

Comment: Duplicate: _ means always the same: Ignore it. The interesting thing is `variable_((*imple)(nil))` which you cannot put into code without a variabel (you do not care about). `variable_((*imple)(nil))` is a compile time check that `*impl` implements `variable_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` always means ignore in GO. the purpose of `_ = variable_((*imple)(nil))` is to check at compile time if `*impl` implements `variable_`